Dynamically created SVG <imgae> element not rendered by the browser
Similar Dynamically created SVG elements are not rendered by the browser but my code already corresponded to their solutions.
I am trying to use SVG markup in my HTML in order to render some texts. The problem was very tricky because I just realized that the issue is when generating the SVG programmatically.
The markup
What I want to end up in my page is this fragment of code:


html {
  background-color: #151515;
  color: white;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/210/500/500);
  background-size: 500px 500px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
  font-family: 'Katahdin Round', 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
}

#navbar .letter-path {
  fill: white;
  stroke: transparent;
  stroke-width: 2.5;
  stroke-dasharray: 400;
  stroke-dashoffset: 400;
  transition: fill 0.1s ease-in 0.1s, stroke 0.25s ease-out, stroke-dashoffset 0s linear 0.25s;
}

#navbar svg:hover .letter-path {
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  stroke: white;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition: fill 0.25s ease-out, stroke 0s, stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease-in 0.1s;
}

#blurred-clip-background {
  clip-path: url(#blur-letter-paths);
  filter: blur(3px);
}
<body>
  <ul id="navbar" class="relative inline-block">
    <li><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" viewBox="0 0 279.468 100">
                <defs>
                    <path id="letter-path-0" class="letter-path-T"
                        d="M27.934 79.496c-3.127 0-4.69-1.564-4.69-4.69V22.06H7.19c-3.127 0-4.691-1.563-4.691-4.69V7.05c0-3.127 1.563-4.69 4.69-4.69h51.807c3.127 0 4.69 1.563 4.69 4.69v10.32c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69H42.944v52.744c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69z"
                        transform="translate(0, 0)"></path>
                    <path id="letter-path-1" class="letter-path-E"
                        d="M56.6 74.805c0 3.127-1.564 4.69-4.692 4.69H7.191c-3.127 0-4.691-1.563-4.691-4.69V7.051c0-3.127 1.563-4.69 4.69-4.69h44.718c3.128 0 4.691 1.563 4.691 4.69v10.32c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69H22.2v9.694h21.89c3.127 0 4.69 1.564 4.69 4.69v8.861c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69H22.2v9.8h29.707c3.128 0 4.691 1.563 4.691 4.69z"
                        transform="translate(69.187, 0)"></path>
                    <path id="letter-path-2" class="letter-path-X"
                        d="M38.05 23.104l11.987-17.72c1.356-1.981 3.336-3.024 5.733-3.024h13.342c3.857 0 5.212 2.502 3.023 5.733L49.933 40.615l22.515 33.148c2.19 3.231.833 5.733-3.023 5.733H56.083c-2.397 0-4.378-1.042-5.734-3.023l-12.3-18.241-12.404 18.241c-1.356 1.98-3.335 3.023-5.733 3.023H6.57c-3.857 0-5.212-2.502-3.023-5.733l22.515-33.148L3.86 8.093C1.67 4.862 3.027 2.36 6.883 2.36h13.342c2.396 0 4.378 1.043 5.733 3.023z"
                        transform="translate(131.286, 0)"></path>
                    <path id="letter-path-3" class="letter-path-T"
                        d="M27.934 79.496c-3.127 0-4.69-1.564-4.69-4.69V22.06H7.19c-3.127 0-4.691-1.563-4.691-4.69V7.05c0-3.127 1.563-4.69 4.69-4.69h51.807c3.127 0 4.69 1.563 4.69 4.69v10.32c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69H42.944v52.744c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69z"
                        transform="translate(210.281, 0)"></path>
                    <clipPath id="blur-letter-paths">
                        <use href="#letter-path-0"></use>
                        <use href="#letter-path-1"></use>
                        <use href="#letter-path-2"></use>
                        <use href="#letter-path-3"></use>
                    </clipPath>
                </defs>
                <image id="blurred-clip-background" x="-40" y="-16" width="500" height="500"
                    href="https://picsum.photos/id/210/500/500"></image>
                <use href="#letter-path-0" class="letter-path"></use>
                <use href="#letter-path-1" class="letter-path"></use>
                <use href="#letter-path-2" class="letter-path"></use>
                <use href="#letter-path-3" class="letter-path"></use>
            </svg></li>
    <!-- <li>PROJECTS</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li> -->
  </ul>

  <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
</body>



If you take this and paste it inside a page, all is fine and the text is rendered!
Creating the SVG dynamically
But I want to create this content using JavaScript, so I have this:


// Dictionary of paths for each letter
const letterPaths = {
    E: "M56.6 74.805c0 3.127-1.564 4.69-4.692 4.69H7.191c-3.127 0-4.691-1.563-4.691-4.69V7.051c0-3.127 1.563-4.69 4.69-4.69h44.718c3.128 0 4.691 1.563 4.691 4.69v10.32c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69H22.2v9.694h21.89c3.127 0 4.69 1.564 4.69 4.69v8.861c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69H22.2v9.8h29.707c3.128 0 4.691 1.563 4.691 4.69z",
    T: "M27.934 79.496c-3.127 0-4.69-1.564-4.69-4.69V22.06H7.19c-3.127 0-4.691-1.563-4.691-4.69V7.05c0-3.127 1.563-4.69 4.69-4.69h51.807c3.127 0 4.69 1.563 4.69 4.69v10.32c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69H42.944v52.744c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69z",
    X: "M38.05 23.104l11.987-17.72c1.356-1.981 3.336-3.024 5.733-3.024h13.342c3.857 0 5.212 2.502 3.023 5.733L49.933 40.615l22.515 33.148c2.19 3.231.833 5.733-3.023 5.733H56.083c-2.397 0-4.378-1.042-5.734-3.023l-12.3-18.241-12.404 18.241c-1.356 1.98-3.335 3.023-5.733 3.023H6.57c-3.857 0-5.212-2.502-3.023-5.733l22.515-33.148L3.86 8.093C1.67 4.862 3.027 2.36 6.883 2.36h13.342c2.396 0 4.378 1.043 5.733 3.023z",
};

const letterWidths = {
    E: 54.099,
    T: 61.187,
    X: 70.995,
}

// Letter spacing constant
const LETTER_SPACING = 8;
const HEIGHT = 100;

// Function to create SVG for a word
function createWordSVG(word)
{
    const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svg.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
    const defs = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'defs');
    const clipPath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'clipPath');
    clipPath.setAttribute('id', 'blur-letter-paths');
    const image = document.createElementNS('https://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image')
    image.setAttribute('id', 'blurred-clip-background');
    image.setAttribute('x', '-40'); // TODO: dynamic depending on svg pos
    image.setAttribute('y', '-16'); // TODO: dynamic depending on svg pos
    image.setAttribute('width', '500');
    image.setAttribute('height', '500');
    image.setAttribute('href', 'https://picsum.photos/id/210/500/500'); // xlink:href didn't work either
    
    svg.appendChild(defs);
    svg.appendChild(image);

    let totalWidth = 0;
    word.toUpperCase().split('').forEach((letter, index) =>
        {
            if (letterPaths[letter])
            {
                defs.appendChild(createLetterPath(letter, index));
                clipPath.appendChild(createLetterUse(index, false))
                svg.appendChild(createLetterUse(index, true))

                totalWidth += letterWidths[letter] + LETTER_SPACING;
            }
        });

    defs.appendChild(clipPath);

    function createLetterPath(letter, index) {
        const path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
        path.setAttribute("id", `letter-path-${index}`)
        path.setAttribute("class", `letter-path-${letter}`)
        path.setAttribute("d", letterPaths[letter]);
        path.setAttribute("transform", `translate(${totalWidth}, 0)`);
        return path
    }

    function createLetterUse(index, isPath) {
        const use = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
        use.setAttribute("href", `#letter-path-${index}`)
        if (isPath) {
            use.setAttribute("class", `letter-path`)
        }
        return use
    }

    svg.setAttribute("height", `${HEIGHT}`);
    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `0 0 ${totalWidth} ${HEIGHT}`);

    return svg;
}

// Main function to replace text in list items with SVGs
function replaceTextWithSVG()
{
    const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

    listItems.forEach(li =>
    {
        const text = li.textContent.trim();
        const svg = createWordSVG(text);
        li.textContent = ''; // Clear the text
        li.appendChild(svg);
    });
}

// Call the function when the document is ready
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', replaceTextWithSVG);
html {
    background-color: #151515;
    color: white;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/210/500/500);
    background-size: 500px 500px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar {
    font-family: 'Katahdin Round', 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
}

#navbar .letter-path {
    fill: white;
    stroke: transparent;
    stroke-width: 2.5;
    stroke-dasharray: 400;
    stroke-dashoffset: 400;
    transition: fill 0.1s ease-in 0.1s, stroke 0.25s ease-out, stroke-dashoffset 0s linear 0.25s;
}

#navbar svg:hover .letter-path {
    fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    stroke: white;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transition: fill 0.25s ease-out, stroke 0s, stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease-in 0.1s;
}

#blurred-clip-background {
    clip-path: url(#blur-letter-paths);
    filter: blur(3px);
}
<body>
    <ul id="navbar" class="relative inline-block">
        <li>TEXT</li>
        <!-- <li>PROJECTS</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li> -->
    </ul>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>



Well, try to execute this in fiddle or in your browser and you'll see it will not be rendered. When you inspect the HTML, you see that the -tag is not taking any space.
What is the problem?
This post is almost the same as the one made by Andry a while ago, where the problem was the creation of svg-elements using createElement instead of createElementNS. This isn't my problem though, because in my case all svg-elements are already generated using the correct way. This becomes apparent, because everything else works, not the -tag though.

The TEXT is rendered in both your snippets (Chrome)

https://www.w3.org/2000/svg is not the SVG namespace. http not https

you'll see it will not be rendered – please be more specific what the desired rendering should look like. The current code shows text but maybe not the way as intended – a screenshot/mockup image may help to illustrate the problem.

Your major problem is not creating those SVGs, but handling duplicate IDs in multiple SVGs
You did not have to face those ID issues yet because your are still working with ONE SVG

Creating NameSpaced SVG nodes is a PITA!
The Browser will do all the Namespaces for you when you provide a SVG as HTML String
You are also going to run into ID troubles, because those are global
Thus your following SVGs (with that same ID) will use the already existing SVG elements in the page.
I have fixed it for the <path>; otherwise <use> would use the first matching ID (set by the first SVG)
and (second word) "TTE" would be displayed as "TEX" (first word letters)
But blur-letter-path is still the same global but duplicate ID.
So all words use the def from the first SVG.  (see TTE in SO snippet still has TEXT as blurred background)
For you to fix.
Note: I would say "shadowDOM" is an option here, as it can scope styles to one word.
Wrapping your code in a native Web Component <svg-word> will simplify your code
AND usage in HTML
(do read this weeks X comments, some "gurus" still claim Web Components suck)
No more need for querySelectorAll("LI") or DOMContentLoaded as Web Components automagically upgrade.
Yes! also when you do
document.body.append(document.createElement("svg-word") anytime later.
When you define the <svg-word> Web Component at start or end of page-load, doesn't matter when or how (script or import)
All HTML required is:
<ul id="navbar" class="relative inline-block">
  <li><svg-word>TEXT</svg-word></li>
  <li><svg-word>TTe</svg-word></li>
  <li><svg-word height="50">EXET</svg-word></li>
</ul>


Full working code:
disclaimer: I probably missed something; refactoring this type of code is not something done in 5 minutes.
(My GPT Bot can create NEW (but half baked) Web Components in 20 seconds)
Code below also available as JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/5g0xvne6/


customElements.define( "svg-word", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() { // default method when <svg-word> is created in the DOM
      setTimeout(() => { // wait till innerHTML (word) is parsed by the browser
        const letterPaths = {
          E: "54.099;M56.6 74.805c0 3.127-1.564 4.69-4.692 4.69H7.191c-3.127 0-4.691-1.563-4.691-4.69V7.051c0-3.127 1.563-4.69 4.69-4.69h44.718c3.128 0 4.691 1.563 4.691 4.69v10.32c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69H22.2v9.694h21.89c3.127 0 4.69 1.564 4.69 4.69v8.861c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69H22.2v9.8h29.707c3.128 0 4.691 1.563 4.691 4.69z",
          T: "61.187;M27.934 79.496c-3.127 0-4.69-1.564-4.69-4.69V22.06H7.19c-3.127 0-4.691-1.563-4.691-4.69V7.05c0-3.127 1.563-4.69 4.69-4.69h51.807c3.127 0 4.69 1.563 4.69 4.69v10.32c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69H42.944v52.744c0 3.127-1.563 4.69-4.69 4.69z",
          X: "70.995;M38.05 23.104l11.987-17.72c1.356-1.981 3.336-3.024 5.733-3.024h13.342c3.857 0 5.212 2.502 3.023 5.733L49.933 40.615l22.515 33.148c2.19 3.231.833 5.733-3.023 5.733H56.083c-2.397 0-4.378-1.042-5.734-3.023l-12.3-18.241-12.404 18.241c-1.356 1.98-3.335 3.023-5.733 3.023H6.57c-3.857 0-5.212-2.502-3.023-5.733l22.515-33.148L3.86 8.093C1.67 4.862 3.027 2.36 6.883 2.36h13.342c2.396 0 4.378 1.043 5.733 3.023z",
        }
        const HEIGHT = this.getAttribute("height") || 100
        const template = document.createElement("template")
        template.addHTML = (el, html) => el.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", html)
        template.tosvg = (tag) => template.content.querySelector(tag)
        template.innerHTML =
          `<svg>` +
          `<defs><clipPath id="blur-letter-paths"/></defs>` +
          `<image id="blurred-clip-background" x="-40" y="-16" width="500" height="500"` +
          ` href="https://picsum.photos/id/210/500/500"/>` +
          `</svg>`
        const svg = template.tosvg("svg")
        let totalWidth = 0
        this.innerHTML.toUpperCase().split("").forEach( letter => {
            let [width, path] = letterPaths[letter].split(";")
            let pathID = "letter-path-" + crypto.randomUUID().replaceAll("-", "")
            if (width) {
              template.addHTML( template.tosvg("defs"),
                `<path id="${pathID}" class="letter-path-${letter}"` +
                  ` d="${path}" transform="translate(${totalWidth}, 0)"/>` )
              template.addHTML( template.tosvg("clipPath"),
                `<use href="#${pathID}"/>` )
              template.addHTML( svg,
                `<use href="#${pathID}" class="letter-path"/>` )
              totalWidth += Number(width) + (this.getAttribute("spacing") || 8)
            }
          })
        svg.setAttribute("height", `${HEIGHT}`)
        svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `0 0 ${totalWidth} ${HEIGHT}`)
        this.replaceChildren(svg)
      }) // setTimeout
    } // connectedCallback
  } // class extend HTMLElement
  ) // define <svg-word>
html {
    background-color: #151515;
    color: white;
    background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/210/500/500);
    background-size: 500px 500px;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navbar {
    font-family: 'Katahdin Round', 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
    list-style: none;
}
#navbar .letter-path {
    fill: white;
    stroke: transparent;
    stroke-width: 2.5;
    stroke-dasharray: 400;
    stroke-dashoffset: 400;
    transition: fill 0.1s ease-in 0.1s, stroke 0.25s ease-out, stroke-dashoffset 0s linear 0.25s;
}
#navbar svg:hover .letter-path {
    fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    stroke: white;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    transition: fill 0.25s ease-out, stroke 0s, stroke-dashoffset 0.5s ease-in 0.1s;
}
#blurred-clip-background {
    clip-path: url(#blur-letter-paths);
    filter: blur(3px);
}
<ul id="navbar" class="relative inline-block">
  <li><svg-word>TEXT</svg-word></li>
  <li><svg-word>TTe</svg-word></li>
  <li><svg-word height="50">EXET</svg-word></li>
</ul>



with shadowDOM
(yes, couldn't resist)
Moved the relevant parts of the global Stylesheet, into a stylesheet inside shadowDOM
So
this.replaceChildren( svg )

Becomes:
this
    .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
    .append(stylesheet,svg)

In JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/cs7kL1dw/

Seems a lot of effort to correct a typo.

Creating ONE SVG is easy. Duplicate IDs is the major issue OP hasn't run into yet, because he is experimenting with one SVG. He wants to show a whole list of LI (conversions to multiple SVG)... I think shadowDOM is his only sane way out, they can also be attached to (his current) LIs, doesn't have to be a Custom Element with shadowDOM
